# Several intervals containing $\sqrt n$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I conjectured the following based on some problem,

**Lemma** : If $n\in \mathbb{N}$ is not a perfect square then $\sqrt n$ lies between $\frac ab$ and $\frac {a+nb}{a+b}$ for any $a,b\in\mathbb{N}$.

**Proof** : Case 1: Lets assume that $\frac ab <\sqrt n$, then if $\frac {a+nb}{a+b} < \sqrt n\Rightarrow a^2+n^2b^2+2abn<na^2+nb^2+2abn\Rightarrow n(n-1)b^2<a^2(n-1)\Rightarrow \frac {a^2}{ b^2}>n$ a contradiction to our assumption.

Similar reasoning follows for the other case.

Please check the proof, and also help me figure out which is bigger $|\frac ab -\sqrt n|$ or $|\frac{a+nb}{a+b}-\sqrt n|$. Is it possible in general, if yes is it different for the two cases or same?

Comment: Do you intend to say for some $a,b \in \mathbb{N}$?

Comment: Neither of $a/b$ and $(a+nb)/(a+b)$ needs to be near $\sqrt{n}$.

Comment: Take $a=1,b=1000, n=10^{12}$. Then $\sqrt n=10^6,$, but $\frac ab=\frac 1{1000}, \frac {a+nb}{a+b} \approx 10^{12}$.  They do bracket $\sqrt n$, but neither is close.

Comment: By close I mean that which is bigger $|\frac ab -\sqrt n|$ or $|\frac{a+nb}{a+b}-\sqrt n|$.